# Create Envelope with access token returns 404 (DocuSign PHP SDK)

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create an envelope through PHP sdk, we have working integration using X-DocuSign-Authentication header (with user, password, integrator key combo). Trying to migrate the integration to access token, but keep on getting 404 Resource not found error from the actual SDK (the resources is dictated by the SDK).

Current code:

```
// DocuSign\eSign\Configuration
$config = new Configuration();
$config->setHost('https://www.docusign.net/restapi');

// DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient
$api = new ApiClient($config);

try {
    $response = $api->requestJWTUserToken(
        "correct-integrators-key",
        "correct-user-id",
        file_get_contents( base_path() . '/ds-private.key', true), //exists
        "signature impersonation",
    );
} 
catch (ApiException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

JWT Token payload comes back successfully, and access token is valid.

```
// DocuSign\eSign\Client\Auth\OAuthToken
if(!$response[0] instanceof OAuthToken)
    return "Auth Token Invalid.";

$access_token = $response[0]->getAccessToken();

try {
    $user = $api->getUserInfo($access_token);
} catch (ApiException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}

// DocuSign\eSign\Client\Auth\UserInfo
if(!$user[0] instanceof UserInfo)
    return "User Info Invalid.";
```

Setting the account ID and base URL also are seemingly correct (account ID comes back as expected, and is correct one, base URL comes back as na2 subdomain, seems to be the correct - this is supported by the fact that "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT" is thrown if any other host is used)

```
$account_id = null;
$base_url = null;

foreach ($user[0]->getAccounts() as $account) {
    if($account instanceof Account)
        if($account->getIsDefault()) {
            $account_id = $account->getAccountId(); // Account ID succeeds, comes back as correct account ID (verified on the admin panel)
            $base_url = $account->getBaseUri(); // Base URL succeeds, comes back as na2 subdomain
        }
}

$config->setAccessToken($access_token); // Access token succeeds

$config->setHost($base_url);
```

This code is practically copy/paste of working example with the "old" integration.

```
$envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($api);

$templateRole = new TemplateRole();
$definition = new EnvelopeDefinition();

$templateRole->setEmail('catchable@gmail.com');
$templateRole->setName('Rebecca Smith');
$templateRole->setRoleName('Correct Role Defined On Template');
$templateRole->setClientUserId('Correct User Id For Embedding');

$signers = [];
$signers[] = $templateRole;

$definition->setTemplateId('Valid Template Id');
$definition->setTemplateRoles($signers);
$definition->setStatus('sent');

try {
    $envelope = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($account_id, $definition);
}
catch (ApiException $e) {
    return [
        'envelope_error_message' => $e->getMessage(), // Returns: "Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [404] with response Body:  "
        'envelope_error_code' => $e->getCode(), // Returns: 404
    ];
}
```

Tried also directly running $api->callApi to check if v2.1 vs v2 in resource path is the issue, but got 404 on both.

Comment: which env are you using? production? or the developer env (demo)? note the URL for auth, is it account.docusign or account-d.docusign?

Comment: Production, and credentials are from production.

Comment: are you sure all the URLs you are using are for production? what about the GUID for the userId for JWT? did you get the correct one from the same account?

Comment: are you using latest PHP SDK?

Comment: Yes. Freshly installed 128 mins ago.

Comment: What do you mean am I sure all the URLs are for production? They are served by the SDK. And we get successful calls for JWT, then for user info using that JWT, it only fails as 404 on envelope create.  For what its worth, yeah all the URLs are production and credentials are production. It is what we already use for X-DocuSign-Authentication.

Comment: so the exact same code, without a single change works with the old token and give you a 404 with the new token?

Comment: may want to confirm the token is good by using postman and see if you can call directly without SDK. Trying to isolate the issue here.

Comment: Already tried the Postman collection from your DS post. Tried creating an envelope and also retrieving a status for an existing one. Both endpoints returned default 404 server page "404 - File or directory not found."

Comment: can you post the URL from postman that gave you 404?

Comment: GET https://na2.docusign.net/v2.1/accounts/{{removed}}/envelopes/{{removed}} and POST https://na2.docusign.net/v2.1/accounts/{{removed}}/envelopes

Comment: Fwiw the DocuSign admin dashboard is having issues too, whatever page I click on I get red alert error "Error in getting the data. Please try after sometime." Pages seemingly still work.

Comment: These URLs are wrong. you are missing the /restapi/ after the .net before v2.1

Comment: so the 404 is expected for these URLs

Comment: $config->setHost($base_url + "/restapi"); should fix it I would think

Answer (score 4):

You need to append `/restapi` to the `baseUri`

Instead of

```
$base_url = $account->getBaseUri(); // Base URL succeeds, comes back as na2 subdomain
```

try

```
$base_uri_suffix = '/restapi';
$base_url = $account->getBaseUri().$base_uri_suffix; // Base URL succeeds, comes back as na2 subdomain
```

See the [source](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/CodeGrantService.php#L100) in the PHP Code Example